# What is the best practice running cypress testing in the CI / CD pipeline?

Tags: node.js, cypress, enterprise

I'm working in a private enterprise and want to integrate `Cypress` E2E tests with our `gitlab` CI / CD pipeline.

Since cypress needs to install a binary zip file, I can't simply run `npm i` and hope things will work right.

I'm facing 3 options and not sure which one is the ideal way:

1. Somehow include the cypress binaries during the CI, cache them, and deploy the app image to both test & dev environments. One will serve for testing and one for the actuall app deployment.
   (if possible, it is the fastest way since it doesn't require additional image building, and I would
   love to see a gitlab-ci.yml example :) )
2. Use 2 different images -

   - `nodejs-8-rhel7` image - which will be used for app deployments (and is being used currently)
   - `cypress-included` image - which will include cypress as well as the app code (and will be used for testing).
     In this case I would have to build the app image twice, one with cypress and one without, looks like a slow process.
3. Use the `cypress-included` image for both app & testing deployments.
   Since our current application base image is `nodejs-8-rhel7`, I'm afraid changing the base image will cause some trouble (nodejs version differences etc..)

Which of the above is the best option? do you have a better solution?

Thanks!